# Getting validator error in Sequelize.js

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

Im trying to validate a username and password to not be null when there is a post request made so that there are no empy rows, but I keep getting

```
Express server listening on port 5000

/Users/ra/Desktop/Jos/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dao-validator.js:216
      throw new Error("Invalid validator function: " + validatorType)
            ^
Error: Invalid validator function: allowNull
```

heres the the employer model

```
'use strict';

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    var Employer = sequelize.define("employer", {
        username: { type: Sequelize.STRING, validate: { allowNull: false } },
        password: { type: Sequelize.STRING, validate: { allowNull: false } }
    });
    return {
        Employer: Employer
    };
};
```

Answer (score 6):

`allowNull` must be in field options, not in validator:
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

```
'use strict';

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

module.exports = function (sequelize) {
    var Employer = sequelize.define("employer", {
        username: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
        password: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }
    });
    return {
        Employer: Employer
    };
};
```

See [doc here](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/models/#validators-andallownull) and [comment of source code here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/30350ab2f3bad4131385183c5913e7f658fd66c7/lib/sequelize.js#L477)

Before Sequelize 2.0 you could use `notNull` validator, but it was removed in 2.0 version (see [2.0 changes here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/Upgrading-to-2.0))

Comment: I ended up using "notNull: true" as a validator and it throws the error correctly. The problem is that it error checks on the database so the server breaks when the error is thrown. To circumvent that, I created a simple conditional statement on the router to test if the req.body.username && req.body.password != null

Comment: @rahul2001 `notNull` validator was deprectaed before 2.0 version and was removed in `2.0`. See here https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/wiki/Upgrading-to-2.0

Comment: Oh, did not know that... thanks. So how would error handling work on the db/model if no validator is used with allowNull? If an error is thrown then my server breaks. Docs don't talk about error handling

Comment: @rahul2001 Server must not breaks, as far as I know. Using `validate` method you'll just get an errors: `model.validate().then(function(errors) { /* do something */ }).